# java regular expression to discover regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I would like to build regular expression which checks if entered string is regular expression so if it contains `|`, `[` and then `]`, `(` and then `)` for example:

```
A0[1-4].*Done or (L1 | L2).*Done'
```

I've build something simple like this: `".[\\[]..[\\]]"` but it doesn't work at all even for simple examples. I tried with Java matcher and just simple `String.matches()`

Comment: A regex to identify regexes... reminds me of [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1313/)

Comment: What exactly should the regex match? A _valid_ regex, or anything that somehow _looks_ like a regex, i.e. contains typical regex-chars?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. The problem is regular expressions describe regular languages. And one of the properties of regular languages is that they are `context-free`, and regex, of course, is not context free. So, regex is not a regular language itself, so couldn't be described by regex. At the same time, Tagir's answer should suit you well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Java own parser to check if the input is regular expression or not:

```
public boolean isRegExp(String pattern) {
    try {
        Pattern.compile(pattern);
        return true;
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```